# a string with wildcard (*) returns the latest used string before the call

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, mv

I am trying to write a shell script to search for files in a certain directory, and if found move them to the current directory.
the call is as follows:

```
bringf filename
```

I could move the files if I specified the names without wildcard for example:

```
bringf file1 file2 file3
```

it brings file1, file2, and file3. But after this, if I tried using wildcard after recovering file1,2,3. as follows :

```
bringf file*
```

it searches for file1 file2 file3, and try to bring them, the weird thing is even when after that I echo file* even in terminal I got :

```
file1 file2 file3
```

the code I used :

```
    NAMES=${@:1}
    echo $NAMES
    for NAME in $NAMES
     do
            echo "the file name is: $NAME "
            if [ -f /home/$USER/folder/$NAME ]   #does the file exist?
             then
                    mv /home/$USER/folder/$NAME $PWD
             fi
    done
```

it outputs :

```
the file name is: file1
the file name is: file2
the file name is: file3
```

although in the directory, I have file1 to file10

also if instead I used `bringf file6 file10` after it when I call `bringf file*` it uses my previous input `file6` `file10`

is it an issue with the wildcard (*)?

thank you in advance

Comment: Having `file1` `file2` `file3` in the current directory, typing `bringf file*` is equivalent to typing `bringf file1 file2 file3`

Comment: @Fravadona in the same directory I have `file4` `file5` `file6` but they were not used when passing `bringf file*`. also if instead I used `bringf file6 file10` after it when I call `bringf file*` it uses my previous input `file6` `file10`

Comment: Well, the point is that the shell expands the glob `file*` **before** running `bringf`, so the arguments of `bringf` will be the results of the glob expansion. Also, pass your script in https://www.shellcheck.net and the the few errors that you have.

Comment: `it outputs :` what happened to `echo $NAMES`? `he code I used :` is has no shebang. Are you sure this is the code you are using?

Comment: @KamilCuk the shebang : `#!/bin/bash` for the output I copied just the part of it, it first printed the `file1 file2 file3` then the `the file name is: file1` and the remaining names to file3